# Converting Number to Percentage in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, arcgis-10.2, personal-geodatabase

Using ArcGIS 10.2 and Personal geodatabase,I have a field with values of Numbers like  **0.461538** and Type of "**Double**".

How can I Export them to new Field in Percentage Format to be shown like 46% or at least round the number to looks like 46 then I can add "%" on label to them?

(Honestly! I do not think this is a good idea for further Analysis!).

Comment: Having the % on the end for display is fine but if you need to run analysis on that field it should stay as a number.

Comment: You will have to do this in a text field since % signs aren't allowed in numeric fields

Comment: So how can I generate Percentage Field in ArcGIS?

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using to try and do this?

Comment: Also, is your data stored in as shapefile or some other format?

Comment: Sorry to not mentioend before I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and A personal geodatabase

Answer (score 5):

you should rather change the display so that you don't duplicate your field.

1) Open your attribute table

2) right click on the name of your field

3) select "properties"

4) Press the icon next to "numeric"

5) select percentage : the number represent a fraction

6) go to the option for rounding (number of decimal places set to 0 )

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the following in your field calculation with the Python parser:

```
round(!yourFieldHere!, 2) * 100
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, but This is not working  I tried both round(!Test !, 2) * 100 and round(![Test]!, 2) * 100 but not working

Comment: Could you walk me through the steps you used to calculate a new field?

Comment: Ok I have a Field in Double Type format and it's name is "Test" I Added a New Field to table called "Res" this time in "Long" format. and used your code to calculate the field

Comment: I just double checked and it worked for me in long, text, float and double.  Make sure the Python parser is selected at the top of the field calculator.  Also, you may need to replace !Test! with !Test_!.

Comment: !Test! is the syntax with Python and [Test] is the syntax with VBA. You need to change the parser to Python in order to use Aaron's code.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this for labeling purposes only, leave the field as it is and label your features using this expression (with the VBScript parser):

```
round([Test]*100) & "%"
```